# Exporting nodes to new drupal instance

Tags: html, mysql, drupal

I've got big (300 articles divided into few content types) and I need to export it to different instance - it got same style of content types but not identical to the previous instance. Should I import over the database table or is there another way?

Comment: What version of Drupal? I think the newer ones have an export DB option, but if your new instance isn't configured the same way, it's possible you'll have to do some tweaking to get everything to appear again after the import.

Comment: Is there already data in the new instance? What is the purpose of migrating to the new instance? Is this moving between dev/test/production environments or a wholesale move from one distinct site to another?

Answer (score 1):

I've always had good luck with [Node Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_export). And the fact that it works with drush and views bulk operations is just a bonus.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't know what you're doing hacking the database is definitely not recommended.

There's modules that assist a data migration such as what you describe here: [Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) module is one of such and is great for migrating both data between Drupal systems (or to move data from a 3rd party into a Drupal system).